# How to Update only new records from .csv file in database using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written code for upload .csv file in database using MVC. How to upload only new records and ignore existing records ?

```
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload) {
            // Set up DataTable place holder 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //check we have a file 
            if (FileUpload.ContentLength > 0) {
                //Workout our file path
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);

                //Try and upload
                try {
                    FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
                    //Process the CSV file and capture the results to our DataTable place holder
                    dt = ProcessCSV(path);

                    //Process the DataTable and capture the results to our SQL Bulk copy
                    ViewData["Feedback"] = ProcessBulkCopy(dt);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    //Catch errors
                    ViewData["Feedback"] = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else {
                //Catch errors
                ViewData["Feedback"] = "Please select a file";
            }

            //Tidy up
            dt.Dispose();

            return View("Index", ViewData["Feedback"]);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process the file supplied and process the CSV to a dynamic datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">String</param>
        /// <returns>DataTable</returns>
        private static DataTable ProcessCSV(string fileName) {
            //Set up our variables 
            string Feedback = string.Empty;
            string line = string.Empty;
            string[] strArray;  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;

            // work out where we should split on comma, but not in a sentance
            Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

            //Set the filename in to our stream
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

            //Read the first line and split the string at , with our regular express in to an array
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = r.Split(line);

            //For each item in the new split array, dynamically builds our Data columns. Save us having to worry about it.
            Array.ForEach(strArray, s => dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()));

            //Read each line in the CVS file until it's empty
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                row = dt.NewRow();

                //add our current value to our data row
                row.ItemArray = r.Split(line);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            //Tidy Streameader up
            sr.Dispose();

            //return a the new DataTable
            return dt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Take the DataTable and using WriteToServer(DataTable) send it all to the database table "BulkImportDetails" in one go
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">DataTable</param>
        /// <returns>String</returns>
        private static String ProcessBulkCopy(DataTable dt) {
            string Feedback = string.Empty;
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            //make our connection and dispose at the end    
            using(  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
                //make our command and dispose at the end
                using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn)) {
                    //Open our connection
                    conn.Open();

                    ///Set target table and tell the number of rows
                    copy.DestinationTableName = "BulkImportDetails";
                    copy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                    try {
                        //Send it to the server
                        copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                        Feedback = "Upload complete";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        Feedback = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Feedback;
       }

        public ActionResult About() {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a tag for the relevant language please

Comment: When is a row new? Do you have anything uniquely identifying data in it? The fastest way I think is to create a table just for upload and afterwards select the items that are new and insert them in the target table.

Comment: But what code should i write to select items that are new and to be inserted in the table ?

Comment: That depends on how you can uniquely identify the rows. Do they have something like an id? How does your csv look like?

Comment: CSV have 3 Columns: ID, Name and DOB.........I have put PK in database table, so now same record can not be inserted.